# Closing modal dialog only on outside click - angular

Tags: angular

I made modal dialog for notifications in the top of my page, when I click on modal dialog it closes, exactly wherever I click it closes, how can I make to close only on outside click
The code is below. I'm using angular 13

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#notificationModal">
                    <i class="icon-bell2" data-toggle="modal"></i>
                    <span class="d-md-none ml-2"></span>
                    <span class="badge border-white ml-auto ml-md-0" style="color: white;">10</span>

                    <div class="modal fade" id="notificationModal" tabIndex="-1" data-backdrop="false">
                        <div class="modal-dialog notification modal-dialog-scrollable">
                            <div class="modal-content notModal">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title col-md-3" id="exampleModalLabel" style="color: black;">
                                        Notifications</h5>
                                    <span class="col-md-7" style="color: black;">Only show unread</span>
                                    <label class="switch col-md-1">
                                        <input type="checkbox">
                                        <span class="slider round"></span>
                                      </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body" style="color: black;">
                                    <hr/>
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                            <div class="col-md-11"
                                                style="padding: 3px; margin-left: 7px; max-width: max-content; color: black; ">
                                                <div class='row' style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                                                    <div
                                                        style="max-width: 250px; word-wrap: break-word; padding: 5px; background-color: #56bde9; border-radius: 10px; ">
                                                        text</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
```

Comment: Please try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which shows the problem. I copied your code into a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-djtp4w?file=src/app/app.component.html) but the modal isn't showing for me when pressing the button.

Comment: how can we here add bootstrap library?, we need that library

Comment: add ts code in your question description, from where you are opening this modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is happening because your modal is wrapped inside the `<a>` tag link that toggles it?  Try moving your modal outside of the `<a>` tag.

On a side note: It appears that you are using a bootstrap modal in this Angular 13 project.  Are you aware that Angular Material has a built in modal service feature called MatDialog?

[Angular Material Dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)